# Permission declared still permission denied

Tags: java, android

I have declared all the permission required (in fact even those which are not required) but still getting error of "permission Denial" and java.lang.RuntimeException.
Basically, I am just reading the various ID including wifi and BT and sending an sms.

Error log.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5260): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ketan.mid/com.ketan.mid.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.MmsSmsProvider uri content://mms-sms/threadID?recipient=9123456789&createthread=true from pid=5260, uid=10108 requires android.permission.READ_SMS
```

Here is the permission declared.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>
```

Pl help me to find out whats wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: _"`uid=10108 requires android.permission.READ_SMS`"_ Where is `android.permission.READ_SMS` ? I don't see it with what you posted.

Comment: Please understand, that READ_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS is not the same thing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have declared all the permission required

The error has `requires android.permission.READ_SMS`, and you have not requested that permission. While in many cases "write implies read", perhaps that is not supported here.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add android.permission.READ_SMS. Because android.permission.WRITE_SMS is the permission to write SMS from the app. We need to add android.permission.READ_SMS explicitly.

Refer the following documentation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SMS
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_SMS